# Augmented Matrix Consistent

Tags: matrices

How would I determine which value of h would make the following matrix consistent for a linear system?

```
1   h  -3
-2  4   6
```

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! The two rows have to be proportional, so $h/4=1/-2$.

Comment: @Bernard Why is not consistent for $h\ne -2?$ (If I am not wrong consistent means the system has a least a solution.)

Comment: Would you write explicitly the system, to avoid any misinterpretation?

Comment: @JMoravitz Maybe I am wrong. But my interpretation of the system is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1& h\\-2&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -3\\6\end{bmatrix}.$$ It has, at least, one solution for any $h.$

Comment: Certainly the system can be consistent for more than one value of $h$.

Comment: Could the OP @Carmella clarify the question?

Comment: The question is: determine the value(s) of h such that the augmented matrix  of a linear system is consistent.

Comment: You must have had a lecture on the subject. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the system
$$\begin{cases}x+hy=-3\\-2x+4y=6\end{cases}$$
and you want to see for what values of $h\in\Bbb R$ this system is consistent.

We look at the augmented matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&h&|&-3\\-2&4&|&6\end{bmatrix}$$
From some elementary row operations ($2\times R_1+R_2\mapsto R_2$) we have the augmented matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&h&|&-3\\0&4+2h&|&0\end{bmatrix}$$
From this wee see that any $h\in\Bbb R$ will produce a consistent system. This is because we obtain a $0$ in the bottom right entry in the augmented matrix above, so $4+2h$ can be equal to anything and the system will be consistent (hence, any $h$ will work).

---

In fact, we can see that the coefficient matrix of the system:
$$A:=\begin{bmatrix}1&h\\-2&4\end{bmatrix}$$
is invertible for any $h$ except $h=-2$ since $\det(A)=4+2h$. So, for any $h\neq -2$ the system is guaranteed to have a solution, so all that's left to check is when $h=-2$, which I will leave to you (but it will be consistent by the earlier argument).

Comment: Thank you Dave! That is very helpful.